# Export ActiveX Control Button in MS Visio File (.vsdm) to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, export, activex, visio

I am currently working on an interactive process map within MS Visio and use ActiveX Control Toggle Buttons to switch between Layers and I also use Hyperlinks to switch between Pages.

When exporting my VS Visio file to a PDF file the hyperlinks work but my Buttons (+ Code) are not exported correctly. They are just "printed" as an Image and are not toggable.

Is there a way to implement the behaviour I desire? Must not necessarily be through ActiveX Control Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve similar effects using Shapes with ShapeSheet formulas as you are currently doing using ActiveX controls. By using shapes you have more control over how they look when exported to PDF.

You could create or reuse existing checkbox or button shapes to toggle the visibility of layers. You could add a function to shape’s double click (EventDblClick) cell to turn and off layer visibility using a double click:

```
  SETF("ThePage!Layers.Visible[2]",IF(ThePage!Layers.Visible[2]=1,0,1))
```

The same formula could be used in the Actions section to turn on and off layer visibility using a right mouse action.
Parts of the shape could be hidden or displayed by putting a reference to the layer’s visibility in NoShow cell of Geometry sections.

You can also have shapes link to other pages like the “Off Page Reference” shapes do in the Flowchart templates. See [Going Off the Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/going-off-the-page/ba-p/237251).